# leaks while adding the objects in for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my program the memory is leaking while adding the **place1** in the **mapArray1**
I have released the `mapArray1` in `dealloc` method. then also leaking where I have to release the `mapArray1`?

```
place1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [place1 setObject:@"1" forKey:@"ID"];
    lati=[array1 objectAtIndex:i];
    [place1 setObject:lati forKey:@"latitude"]; 
    long i = [array2 objectAtIndex:i];
    [place1 setObject:longi forKey:@"longitude"];
    [mapArray1 addObject:[place1 copy]];
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: I think this `[place1 copy]` is leaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak is coming from `[place1 copy]`. Either replace it with `[[place1 copy] autorelease]` or use a temporary variable and release it after you add it to mapArray1.

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH):

*You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “**copy**”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.*

Also, I doubt you  need to recreate those autorelease polls in each cycle...